# IndexOutOfBoundsException issue with ArrayAdapter Class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to figure out why am I receiving the following error.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.modup.adapter.WorkoutCardsAdapter.getItem(WorkoutCardsAdapter.java:75)
        at com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment$1.onPressed(CreateFragment.java:143)
        at com.modup.adapter.WorkoutCardsAdapter$1.onClick(WorkoutCardsAdapter.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have seen many posts on this topic, but they all seem to have the same answer, and after implementing those answers it seems as if the issue still persists.

**My Case:**

I have a class that extends ArrayAdapter<>, and this Adapter class is used to populate a ListView inside my fragment. Everything works fine, I can add views, and I can remove views (sort of), I can access the callback implemented.

**The Problem:**
It seems as if that when I add many views 3-4+ and start to remove them that I will eventually hit this exception.

Specific Cases: 
If I start from the top view list item, and go down I don't seem to throw an error, and also I can sometimes go from the bottom up. The error seems to come in if I remove the views out of order (sometimes).

**How can I fix this issue? Am I Overriding getCount() and getItem() incorrectly?**

UPDATE:

When checking the position of the mCallback.onPress(position); it appears as if the position of the first item in the list is 0, and will remain 0 as long as I don't try to remove any list item below it. Once I remove a list item below it, the first list item will have a completely different position.

public class WorkoutCardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String[] repArray, setArray, mgArray;
String TAG = WorkoutCardsAdapter.class.getCanonicalName();
Callback mCallback;
List<WorkoutView> mViews;

public WorkoutCardsAdapter(Context context, List<WorkoutView> views, Callback callback) {
    super(context, 0, views);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mCallback = callback;
    this.mViews = views;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_workout_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.spinnerReps = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerReps);
        holder.spinnerSets = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSets);
        holder.spinnerMuscleGroup = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerWorkoutGroup);
        holder.etWorkoutName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etWorkoutName);
        holder.btnRemoveWorkout = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveWorkout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.btnRemoveWorkout.setTag(position);

    mgArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_muscle_groups);
    TextSpinnerAdapter adapter = new TextSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_item, mgArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinnerMuscleGroup.setAdapter(adapter);

    setArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_sets);
    TextSpinnerAdapter adapter1 = new TextSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_item, setArray);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinnerSets.setAdapter(adapter1);

    repArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_reps);
    TextSpinnerAdapter adapter2 = new TextSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_item, repArray);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinnerReps.setAdapter(adapter2);

    holder.btnRemoveWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            mCallback.onPressed(position);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

@Override
    public WorkoutView getItem(final int position) {
        return mViews.get(position);
    }

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mViews.size();
}

public interface Callback {
    void onPressed(int pos);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public Spinner spinnerMuscleGroup;
    public Spinner spinnerSets;
    public Spinner spinnerReps;
    public EditText etWorkoutName;
    public Button btnRemoveWorkout;
}
```

}

Here is the Adapter Implementation w/ Callback

```
mWorkoutCardsAdapter = new WorkoutCardsAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList, new WorkoutCardsAdapter.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onPressed(int pos) {
            mWorkoutCardsAdapter.remove(mWorkoutCardsAdapter.getItem(pos));
            mWorkoutCardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

In case it will help, this is how I add a new view on button press

```
    workoutView = new WorkoutView(getActivity());
    mWorkoutCardsAdapter.add(workoutView);
    mWorkoutCardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the `onPressed` method, what is the value of `pos` if you click on the very first item in your list?

Comment: The position = 0, and will remain 0 if I continue to remove the first item. I checked the position of the last item in the list when I removed it and it was also 0. When I returned to remove the item at the top of the list (first position) the position would then change to 3 or some other number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're not caching the correct position with the corresponding Button, so the items being removed are getting mixed up. You can set the Button's tag to the position, and retrieve it from the View passed into the `onClick()` method, to ensure the right one is removed from the list.

```
holder.btnRemoveWorkout.setTag(position);
holder.btnRemoveWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        mCallback.onPressed(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried to implement this, it didn't seem to work as the position seems to be changing based on which list item I am pressing the button on. I updated my question to reflect my findings.

Comment: @ItzHoudini Well, that's what this should fix, if it's implemented correctly. Also, keep in mind that when an item is removed from an ArrayList, the remaining items will reorder from 0 to size-1.

Comment: I just noticed that when I press btnRemoveWorkout button that corresponds to a view, it always removes the bottom view. It is not removing the view associated with the btnRemoveWorkout press. Also, If i change a value on one of the views, it looks if there are other views within the some of them are getting the changes as well (if i set a spinner value in list item 1, then list item 3 and 5 will have the same value)

Comment: Make sure the `setTag()` call comes after the `if-else` block. Generally, the only thing you want in the `convertView == null` case is the ViewHolder instantiation and initialization, so you might want to move some other stuff after the `if-else` as well.

Comment: I just updated it if you want to take a look. I am actually not sure if the bottom list item is always being removed. I believe that whenever I remove a list_item, any values that were set in other list view items are reset to normal. I can set spinner values on a top item and then if I btnRemoveWorkout on any other item than all them just get reset to there standard. This also happens when I add a list view item.

Comment: Changing the getView() method to what it is now seems to have solved the issue with the indexArrayOutOfBounds. I am going to post another question for my other issue.

Comment: @ItzHoudini Sorry, I actually meant initialize the ViewHolder and its Views; so everything before the `holder.btnRemoveWorkout.setTag(position);` line should go the the `if` block. Also, your description of the Spinner behavior is not unexpected. You're not saving any changes made to the Spinners in the underlying data, and therefore not setting the previously chosen values in `getView()`. The data class should be structured so that `getView()` can return the correctly setup View given a null convertView and an arbitrary position.

Comment: I will take a look into storing the values some how, does the getView() method look right now?

Comment: @ItzHoudini Bingo. I also wanted to mention that, since every `btnRemoveWorkout` uses the same `OnClickListener`, you could just create one as a class member, and set them all to that.